# latex2rtf omits space symbols in every unicode paragraph until first ASCII symbol

Tags: latex2rtf

I have written a LaTeX document in Russian. Unfortunately I have to convert it into a Word compatible format and latex2rtf seems to be the best tool for it.

But there is problem with white space in every paragraph: they are simply omitted until the first ASCII symbol - usually a dot or a number - appears. And paragraphs which start with ASCII symbols are rendered completely normal.

Here's a minimal example to demonstrate this problem:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\begin{document}
\section{Введение}
    Тестовое предложение 1 2 3 4 5. Тестовое предложение. Тестовое предложение.

    Тестовое предложение 1 2 3 4 5. Тестовое предложение. Тестовое предложение.

    English sentence. Русское предложение.
\end{document}
```

Output of `latex2rtf test.tex` can be found [here](http://rghost.ru/download/59418173/77f76b6792482d0772aa3f352347163591d8a59d/test.rtf).

This command is executed under

- Debian 7 operating system,
- latex2rtf version is 1.9.19.

What can I do to solve this problem?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The manual page mentions that `utf8` support is limited and the STIX fonts need to be on the system to get some symbols.

Comment: you can use `tex4ht` to convert your document to `odt` format (which Word can open). try `mk4ht oolatex test.tex`, your document was converted correctly when I tried that

Comment: this would require some extra work, but you might just put a period as the first input to the file, and delete it later.